# Releasing Locked/In-use COM Port

Tags: windows, com-port

I'm developing an USB driver for an embedded device, which appears to Windows as a CDC (virtual COM) device.  I'm using [Free Serial Port Monitor](http://www.serial-port-monitor.com/) and [Realterm](http://realterm.sourceforge.net/) to interact with the device.

Whenever I reset the device the COM port effectively disappears from the system, even though it may be "open" by these utilities.  When the device is restarted the COM port re-appears in Device Manager, as expected.  However, neither Free Serial Port Monitor or Realterm can find it.  My suspicion is that the port is somehow locked.

I need a tool for observing any locks on COM ports and a way of unlocking the port, short of rebooting the computer, which I've been doing (very time consuming).  Does such a utility exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disabling the device in Device Manager, and then re-enabling it, freed the device for use.